# Is the second "on" necessary in this sentence?

Tags: prepositions, american-english, prepositional-objects

> “It still makes economic sense” to put on as much weight on as efficiently as you can, to minimize losses” feedlot owner Tom Fanning told Bloomberg.

https://www.voanews.com/a/mht-good-news-for-burger-lovers-beef-prices-fall/3092061.html

here:

> to put on as much weight on as efficiently as you can

the second "on" here makes me confused!

Comment: "the second "on" here makes me confused!" - that's because it shouldn't be on there ;)

Comment: The word "on" here is not being used as a preposition. If it were a preposition then it would have an object.

Answer (score 34):

There should only be one adverb, although it can be in either location:

- to put **on** as much weight as efficiently as you can
- to put as much weight **on** as efficiently as you can

Comment: +1. This, incidentally, is a very common sort of mistake, including (especially?) by native speakers, though I think it's more common in speech than in writing. No one thinks that "put on X on" is *correct*, but it's very easy to get through "put on X" and then not be sure whether you'd already said the "on".

Comment: I'll bet the second "on" snuck itself in somewhere in the editing process. The second close-quote doesn't have a matching open-quote either, so frankly it smells like the final draft just never got proofread.

Comment: @Lee: I know we're both guessing here. But I think the second "on" was there first, and was then changed to the first "on" (to avoid the semantical ambiguity between e.g. "to **put on** weight" and "to put weight **on the table**"), and they forgot to remove the initial (second) "on".

Comment: The verbal phrase is "to put on"  a dictionary link, or an explanation would make this a better and more detailed answer.

Comment: I might go further than Mari-Lou and say that the idiom here is "put on weight." We can't generally use "put on" as a synonym for "gain" (or in this case "induce *somebody else* to gain"), e.g. if I get a raise at work, I haven't "put on income"; but ["put on weight"](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/put+on+weight) is an idiom. (The OP clearly already knew this, though; they were just confused by the proofreading error.)

Comment: I frequently see errors like this in my town newspaper. I think proofreading has gone the way of the dodo, with reporters probably just depending on their computer's spell-check (some of the most common errors are incorrect synonyms).

Comment: The word "on" is being used here as an adverb, not as a preposition. If it were a preposition, then it would say on something or on someone.

Comment: @MichaelHardy You're right. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

As an aside to the original question, for me there is a difference between "to put on weight" and "to put weight on".

The first case implies that the subject and object are the same person. "I've been putting on weight" = "I am the one who is heavier now."

The second case sounds much less common to me. It implies the work of a farmer or animal breeder or anxious parent: Person A provides fattening food for Person-or-Animal B.

I'm guessing that the original "on" was the first one, and that, on re-reading, the writer thought: "Ah, it sounds as if the farmer is gaining weight. I should move that 'on' on a bit further, to avoid ambiguity."